# Create nested json lines from pipe delimited flat file using python

Tags: python, flat-file, nested-json

I have a text file pipe delimited as below. In that file for same ID, CODE and NUM combination we can have different INC and INC_DESC

```
ID|CODE|NUM|INC|INC_DESC
"F1"|"W1"|1|1001|"INC1001"
"F1"|"W1"|1|1002|"INC1002"
"F1"|"W1"|1|1003|"INC1003"
"F2"|"W1"|1|1002|"INC1003"
"F2"|"W1"|1|1003|"INC1004"
"F2"|"W2"|1|1003|"INC1003"
```

We want to create json like below where different INC and INC_DESC should come as an array for same combination of ID, CODE and NUM

```
{"ID":"F1","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1001, "INC_DESC":"INC1001"},{"INC":1002, "INC_DESC":"INC1002"},{"INC":1003, "INC_DESC":"INC1003"}]}
{"ID":"F2","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1002, "INC_DESC":"INC1002"},{"INC":1003, "INC_DESC":"INC1003"}]}
{"ID":"F2","CODE":"W2","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1003, "INC_DESC":"INC1003"}]}
```

I tried below but it is not generating nested as I want

```
import pandas as pd

Input_File=f'V:\input.dat'
df=pd.read_csv(Input_File, sep='|')

json_output=f'V:\outfile.json'
output=df.to_json(json_output, orient='records')
```

Comment: And what you show as expected output is **not** [valid] JSON. It is `ndjson`/`jsonlines`

Comment: yes individual json line group by ID, CODE and NUM

Comment: Why are F2 and W2 in the same dictionary?

Comment: @Vlad - The last row is having the combination of F2,W2 and 1

Comment: @KoushikChandra "F1"|"W2"|1|1003|"INC1003"

Comment: @Vlad - Sorry this was a typo. I corrected in the source data now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


# agg function
def agg_that(x):
    l = [x]
    return l


Input_File = f'V:\input.dat'
df = pd.read_csv(Input_File, sep='|')

# groupby columns
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'CODE', 'NUM']).agg(agg_that).reset_index()
# create new column
df['INC_DTL'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [{'INC': inc, 'INC_DESC': dsc} for inc, dsc in zip(x['INC'][0], x['INC_DESC'][0])], axis=1)
# drop old columns
df.drop(['INC', 'INC_DESC'], axis=1, inplace=True)

json_output = f'V:\outfile.json'
output = df.to_json(json_output, orient='records', lines=True)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"ID":"F1","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1001,"INC_DESC":"INC1001"},{"INC":1002,"INC_DESC":"INC1002"},{"INC":1003,"INC_DESC":"INC1003"}]}
{"ID":"F1","CODE":"W2","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1003,"INC_DESC":"INC1003"}]}
{"ID":"F2","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[{"INC":1002,"INC_DESC":"INC1003"},{"INC":1003,"INC_DESC":"INC1004"}]}
```

Comment: It is writing as a whole json and not individual lines

Comment: I've updated my answer. Just add lines=True to the to_json parameters

Comment: I am getting output as below:

Comment: {"ID":"F1","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[]}          {"ID":"F1","CODE":"W2","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[]}  {"ID":"F2","CODE":"W1","NUM":1,"INC_DTL":[]}

Comment: This is how I am getting the output

Comment: did you happen to check df right after the grouping? does it group INC and INC_DESC into a list of a list?